# serial communication between Arduino and Nodemcu

Tags: arduino, nodemcu, serial-communication

I'm trying to read voltage value using Analog pin A0 in arduino uno and transmit the read voltage to Nodemcu  but not getting same voltage at NodeMcu as on Arduino side for Ex. for 5 volt at Arduino i get only 4 volt at Nodemcu.

i have made the delay of both the sketches equal even tried without any delay 
also tried connecting the ground pin of both device

```
                          ARDUINO CODE


  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
  SoftwareSerial s(5,6);


  void setup() {

  s.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }


  void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int ADCdata = analogRead(A0);

 float voltage = (ADCdata * 0.0048828125);
 Serial.println(ADCdata);
 Serial.println(voltage);
 if(s.available()>0)
  {
   s.write(voltage);
  }
 delay(1000);
 }

                         NODEMCU CODE

    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial s(D6,D5);


    void setup() {
    s.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    void loop() {

    s.write("s");
    if (s.available()>0)
    {
    data=s.read();
    Serial.println(data);
    }
     delay(1000);
   }
```

Comment: [`s.write(voltage);`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/write) Will write `sizeof(float)` bytes. On the receiving side, you need to read that many bytes and reassemble as a `float`.

Comment: In that case can u suggest some alternative

Comment: You could send as string with `Serial.println(value)` and read with `data = Serial.parseFloat()`.

Comment: but Serial.println() is for printing on Serial monitor correct me if i'm wrong .

Comment: Sorry, forgot you were using `SoftwareSerial`. Yes, it should be `s.println(value)` and `s.parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would send the float data as a string:

```c++
s.println(value)
```

This will append a newline to mark the end of the string.

On the receiving side, read the line and convert to float.

```c++
float value = s.parseFloat();
```